# trim additional line breaks being added in email body from imap_open

Tags: php

I am using the following functions to retrieve the body of emails while using PHP's `imap_open` function.

it's called simply by `$email_body = getBody($email_number, $inbox);`

It works really well, but 1 issue I have sometimes is emails with line breaks end up having extra line breaks added.

Can I tried the additional line breaks being added?

```
function getBody($uid, $imap) {
    $body = get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
    // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
    if ($body == "") {
        $body = get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    return nl2br($body);
}

function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false) {
    if (!$structure) {
        //$structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid);
    }
    //var_dump($structure);
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            //$text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID);
            $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                case 3: return imap_base64($text);
                case 4: return imap_qprint($text);
                default: return $text;
           }
       }

        // multipart 
        if ($structure->type == 1) {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                $prefix = "";
                if ($partNumber) {
                    $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                }
                $data = get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                if ($data) {
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function get_mime_type($structure) {
    $primaryMimetype = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");

    if ($structure->subtype) {
       return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all extra new lines by using `preg_replace`.

```
preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $your_email_body);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete the end of lines at the end of the body, you can simply [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) your body before calling nl2br :

```php
  return nl2br(trim($body));
```

If you also want to remove the double line jumps that would be inside the body, you can add this in addition to the trim:

```php
  $body = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $body);
```